# How to fix "Unable to process Jar entry [...] for annotations" error in Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, maven-plugin, tomcat7-maven-plugin

I'm using tomcat7-maven-plugin version 2.2 along with spring version 5.1.6.RELEASE, hibernate-core 5.4.1.Final dependencies.
When I'm running tomcat7:run goal I'm getting following errors:

I thought maybe some dependencies are causing the issue so I started removing dependencies one by one and found that hibernate-core dependency is causing the issue.

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/CHARAN/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/CHARAN/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.5/byte-buddy-1.9.5.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/CHARAN/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/staxex/stax-ex/1.8/stax-ex-1.8.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/CHARAN/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/CHARAN/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/FastInfoset/1.2.15/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/CHARAN/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.1/txw2-2.3.1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/CHARAN/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.7/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMvcJpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```